# How can I send email using Mailgun and the PHP API?

Tags: php, email, mailgun

I have successfully installed the Mailgun API using composer. And have successfully validated the domain name using DNS records and the Mailgun web GUI.

When using the test script provided on [Github](https://github.com/mailgun/mailgun-php), the server returns a HTTP ERROR 500 error.

What should I change to be able to send email using the PHP API?

```
<?php
    # Include the Autoloader (see "Libraries" for install instructions)
    require 'vendor/autoload.php';
    use Mailgun\Mailgun;

    # Instantiate the client.
    $mg = Mailgun::create('my-api-key');

    // # Make the call to the client.
    $mg->messages()->send('sub.domain.com', [
        'from'    => 'contact@example.com',
        'to'      => 'firsname.lastname@example2.com',
        'subject' => 'Sample Subject',
        'text'    => 'Sample text.'
    ]);
?>
```

Note that these are just sample parameters for this question, but the parameters I am actually passing in share the same format.

Comment: 500 is a server error. Check your logs, enable error reporting.

Comment: "Uncaught Mailgun\Exception\HttpClientException: The parameters passed to the API were invalid." - How are these parameters above incorrect?

Comment: Better cross-reference with the Mailgun API documentation and be sure you're not missing something.